# Permutations in a multiple choice environment

Tags: combinatorics

Looking at a problem that states there are 3 multiple choice questions, each with 4 possible answers each (lets call them A, B, C, and D for all 3 questions), I know that finding the total possible amount of permutations is as simple as the rule of products where 4 x 4 x 4 = 64 possible permutations of the answers but when I try to apply the counting rule of "nPr" to the problem I become quite lost. added to this is the fact that my statistics teacher tried to show us the amount of permutations here through a tree diagram, but did it incorrectly, only accounting for 12 permutations.

Comment: I don't see a question. If you're asking if the number of possible answer sheets is $4^3=64$, then yes, that's correct. The order of the problems are relevant, so combinations are not appropriate. And permutations also don't apply, since the same letter can be reused.

Comment: And if your teacher confused the issues, use standard, well regarded _books_ as your trusted source.